# combining two columns to one in R

Tags: r, function

```
V1<-c("Apple", "Orange", "NA", "NA")
V2<-c("NA", NA", "Strawberries", "NA")
V3<-data.frame(V1, V2)
```

Want to get the following:

```
V4<-c("Apple", "Orange", "Strawberries", "NA")
V4<-data.frame(V4)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: What is the rule if you have values at the same index both for V1 or V2 ? First ? Second ? Any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the possibility to use `case_when` from dplyr.
I like it because it is much easier to keep track of what is happening compared to nested `ifelse` clauses:

```
library(dplyr)

V1<-c("Apple", "Orange", "NA", "NA")
V2<-c("NA", "NA", "Strawberries", "NA")
V3<-data.frame(V1, V2)


V3 <- V3 %>%
mutate(V4 = case_when(V1 == "NA" & V2 != "NA" ~ as.character(V2),
                    V1 != "NA" & V2 == "NA" ~ as.character(V1),
                    TRUE ~ as.character("NA") ) )
```

In this case the difference is probably not so big, but the more conditions are tested, the easier it gets. If for instance you also need to treat the case where there is a non-"NA" value in both columns, this would simply extend to something like:

```
V1<-c("Apple", "Orange", "NA", "NA", "Banana")
V2<-c("NA", "NA", "Strawberries", "NA", "Pear")
V3<-data.frame(V1, V2)


V3 <- V3 %>%
mutate(V4 = case_when(V1 == "NA" & V2 != "NA" ~ as.character(V2),
                    V1 != "NA" & V2 == "NA" ~ as.character(V1),
                    V1 != "NA" & V2 != "NA" ~ paste(V1,V2),
                    TRUE ~ as.character("NA")  ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
V1<-c("Apple", "Orange", "NA", "NA")
V2<-c("NA", "NA", "Strawberries", "NA")
V3<-data.frame(V1, V2)


V3$V4 <- with(V3, ifelse(V1 == "NA" & V2 != "NA", as.character(V2), 
                         ifelse(V1 != "NA" & V2 == "NA", as.character(V1), "NA")))
```

This gives:

```
      V1           V2           V4
1  Apple           NA        Apple
2 Orange           NA       Orange
3     NA Strawberries Strawberries
4     NA           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`'s `coalesce`, also reading in the strings not as factors:

```
V1<-c("Apple", "Orange", NA, NA)
V2<-c(NA, NA, "Strawberries", NA)
V3 <-data.frame(V1, V2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
V3 %>% mutate(V4 = coalesce(V1, V2))

      V1           V2           V4
1  Apple           NA        Apple
2 Orange         <NA>       Orange
3   <NA> Strawberries Strawberries
4   <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
```